# How to make HTTPS calls (POST requests) using WinHTTP on C++?

Tags: c++, https, winhttp

I'm writing program on C++ to make calls (POST requests) to Java Servlets using WinHTTP.  When I request POST via HTTP everything is OK, problem occurs when I request via HTTPS. It sends empty requests to the server but cuts off request body (but it has content)

```
int sendPostRequest(char *pszPostData, LPCTSTR servletUrl, char* resultBuffer, ofstream &outputFile) {

    outputFile << "====================================== SENDING REEQUEST ======================================" << endl;

    HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(
        userAgent,
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS,
        0);
    if (!hSession)
    {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Failed to open WinHTTP session: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Failed to open WinHTTP session: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Oppening WinHTTP session successful: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Oppening WinHTTP session successful: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    HINTERNET hConnect = WinHttpConnect(
        hSession,
        serverIP,
        serverPort,
        0);
    if (!hConnect)
    {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Failed to connect to server: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Failed to connect to server: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Connection to server successful: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Connection to server successful: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    _tprintf(_TEXT("Post data : %ld\n"), pszPostData);
    outputFile << "Post data : %ld\n" << pszPostData << endl;
    DWORD dwDataLen = strlen(pszPostData);

    HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(
        hConnect,
        _TEXT("POST"),
        servletUrl,
        NULL,
        WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
        WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
        WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH);
    if (!hRequest)
    {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Failed to open request: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Failed to open request: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Opening request successful: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Opening request successful: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    DWORD dwReqOpts = 0;
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    WinHttpSetOption(
        hRequest,
        WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
        &dwReqOpts,
        sizeof(DWORD));

    BOOL done = false;
    BOOL rc = WinHttpSendRequest(
        hRequest,
        contentTypeHeader,
        -1,
        (LPVOID)pszPostData,
        dwDataLen,
        dwDataLen,
        NULL);

    if (rc) {
        rc = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Sending request successful: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Sending request successful: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("Send request failed: %ld\n"), GetLastError());
        outputFile << "Send request failed: %ld\n" << GetLastError() << endl;
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
        return -1;
    }

    // Get the status from the server
    DWORD dwCode = 0;
    if (rc)
    {
        rc = WinHttpQueryHeaders(
            hRequest,
            WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
            NULL,
            &dwCode,
            &dwSize,
            NULL);
    }

    if (dwCode != HTTP_STATUS_OK)
    {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("HTTP Request failed: %ld\n"), dwCode);
        outputFile << "HTTP Request failed: %ld\n" << dwCode << endl;
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(_TEXT("HTTP Request is ok: %ld\n"), dwCode);
        outputFile << "HTTP Request is ok : %ld\n" << dwCode << endl;

        // Keep reading from the remote server until there's nothing left to read
        DWORD dwBytesToBeRead = 0, dwBytesRead = 0;
        //char szBuffer[8192] = { 0 };
        //strcpy(resultBuffer, "");
        do
        {
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwBytesToBeRead))
            {
                _tprintf(_TEXT("No data available from server? %ld"), GetLastError());
                outputFile << "No data available from server? %ld" << GetLastError() << endl;

                WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
                WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
                WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
                return -1;
            }

            if (!WinHttpReadData(
                hRequest,

                //szBuffer,
                resultBuffer,

                //sizeof(szBuffer),
                RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE,

                &dwBytesRead))
            {
                _tprintf(_TEXT("Failed to read data from server: %ld"), GetLastError());
                outputFile << "Failed to read data from server: %ld" << GetLastError() << endl;

                WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
                WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
                WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
                return -1;
            }
            if (dwBytesRead > 0)
            {
                //szBuffer[dwBytesRead] = 0;
                resultBuffer[dwBytesRead] = 0; // NULL-terminated returned buffer
            }
        } while (dwBytesRead > 0);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Where `pszPostData` - content of request body, `servletUrl` - url to Servlet (endpoint), `resultBuffer` - call result will be written to this buffer, `outputFile` - file for logs.

So how to make HTTPS calls without cutting of request body?

Comment: Since you've got Java tagged, why not just write the console program in Java?

Comment: @developerwjk, it is written in c++

Comment: @NurzhanAitbayev Do you get any working solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding *WinHttpSendRequest* method, at the 2nd paramaet insert: `L"content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and on the 3rd paramer `-1` which is according to w3.

It should work with this correction.

Also, check the encoding of your .php file, gave me a trouble once.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today as I was facing a very similar issue.  In `WinHttpConnect()` I was sending `pswzServerName` as 'example.com'.  Problem is, in Apache, I was forcing a redirect on `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` and also `http` to `https`.  This redirect was causing no POST data to be sent, wrong content-length header, and wrong content-type header because I had specified `example.com` in `WinHttpConnect()`.

**Two solutions worked with the last being the best choice :**

```
Removing my htaccess non-www to www and http to https redirect

OR

just changing `pswzServerName` to 'www.example.com' (including the www.) in WinHttpConnect()
```

Spent a long time trying to figure out why winhttp wasn't working as this was easily overlooked so hopefully it helps someone else that might be in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is an old question, this might be helpful: 
Add `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE` to the `WinHttpOpenRequest`, and it should work.

```
...
HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(
        hConnect,
        _TEXT("POST"),
        servletUrl,
        NULL,
        WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
        WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
        WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH+WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE); /// Here
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).